# How can i sort with filter A-Z after getting the fetch values on page with POST method?

Tags: php, mysql

User first search for specified "doctors" at it redirects to the "search.php" page. Then it shows the results from database.What i want is , when the user is seeing the results to sort them "A-Z". If you need also the place when users searches for "specified doctors i will post it,just thought you would not need it :)

```
<?php
include 'models/doctors.class.php';
// error_reporting(0);
$search = new doctors();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$s= $search->filterDoctors($_POST);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/search.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/sanascout-font.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/logo-ssc1.png">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Healthcare</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- <section>
        <div class="container-fluid firstSectionn">
            <div class="popins-font">
                <p class="searchHere text-center"><i class="bi bi-arrow-left-short pull-left"></i>Zürich <i class="bi bi-chat-dots pull-right"></i></p>
            </div>
        </div> -->
    <section>
        <div class="container-fluid thisContainerBGColor popins-font">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col text-center pt-4 pb-3">
                <a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)" class="text-decoration-none text-light"> <i
                            class="bi bi-arrow-left-short"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center lh-1 pt-3 pb-3">
                    <span class="span-selected-area">Selected area</span> <br>
                    <span class="span-place">
                        <?php
                            $i = 0;
                            foreach($s as $row){
                                echo $row['location'];
                                $i++;
                                if($i == 1){
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            
                <div class="col text-center pt-4 pb-3">
                    <!-- <i class="bi bi-chat-dots"></i> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </section>
    <section>
        <section class="searched-area mt-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header66">
                    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                        <p class="fs-6 popins-font fw-bold" id="text-color">Available Doctors</p>
                        <!-- <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">
                            <p class="fs-6 popins-font fw-bold" id="text-color">See all</p>
                        </a> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Filter-A-Z</a>
        <div>
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
        }
        ?>
        </div>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <?php
                foreach($s as $row1){
            ?>
                <a href="therapist.php?id=<?php echo $row1['User_ID']; ?>" class="text-decoration-none">
                    <div class="therapistCardOne mx-2 popins-font my-2">
                        <div class="row py-2">
                            <div class="col-3 g-0">
                                <div class="imgW text-center g-0 ps-2">
                                    <img src="assets/images/006.png" class="img-fluid ms-2" alt="" width="70px"
                                        height="80px">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-8 g-0 ps-2">
                                <span class="span1"><?php echo $row1['full_name'];?></span>
                                <span class="ps-2">
                                    <i class="bi bi-star-fill icon-ccc"></i>
                                    <i class="bi bi-star-fill icon-ccc"></i>
                                    <i class="bi bi-star-fill icon-ccc"></i>
                                    <i class="bi bi-star-fill icon-ccc"></i>
                                    <i class="bi bi-star icon-ccc"></i></span><br>
                                <span class="span2">Location :
                                    <?php echo $row1['location'];?>
                                </span> <br>
                                <span class="span3"><i class="bi bi-clock icon-cc"></i> 12:00pm - 16:00pm</span> <span
                                    class="span4 ps-2"><i class="bi bi-geo-alt icon-cc"></i> Zurich New Clinic</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-1 g-0 pe-2">
                                <i class="bi bi-three-dots-vertical"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <?php 
                }
            }
            else {
                header("Location:therapist-list.php");
            }
            ?>
        </section>
```

Comment: I don't see any SQL, remove the tag [mysql] unless you can show us why it is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax and a php function ,

Create a form inside the search.php
And then save the post that you used to redirect to search.php ,
And use php function to order the doctors.